# newtonsoft serializer on dates gives different result

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following lines of code.

```
HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(sBuilder)))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this.Data);
}

response.Write(sBuilder.ToString());
```

it's responsible for EVERY C# to javascript output in web application.

that said I can't change it fully ( i tried, lots of errors, unfortunately )

the problem is, it gets wrong dates, in my case date of births ( dob )

```
ex: dob = { 1993 - 03 - 16 - 00 : 00 : 00 }
```

after serialize(write), dob becomes { 1993 - 03 - 15 - 23 : 00 : 00 , GMT + 3 }

And I want serialize to stop doing that.

I checked newtonsoft for documentation, but 0 help.

I tried altering

```
serializer.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
serializer.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
serializer.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
serializer.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

these to every possible mode.

still same result.

I checked other so questions, which suggest to deserialize, but I can't do that ( or can I? )

so, if you know some sollution, I would be glad.

just to add some more info, on some dates, I get xx - xx - xx : aa:aa:aa gmt + 5 or something

I can't understand what's difference there.

thanks.

Comment: You must have some kind of Culture problem in your DateTime object. Check it before serialize to see the Culture, the zone and see if that make sense.

Comment: How do you construct your `DateTime`?  If you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, it's more likely that we will be able to help.